# Is this a safe design for an input at a 74HCT165

Tags: npn, shift-register, input, pnp

I'm new to designing my own circuits so please be kind and tell me if I'm right with my thoughts or if I have errors in it. Thanks!

The purpose of the 12V is to compensate the resistance of long wires (up to 60m). S1 will be normally closed. As long as S1 is closed Q2 should connect ground to Q1 and light up LED1 and pull D7 high.

R1 = Resistor for the LED and limiting the current through D7, R2 = Limit the current through Q2, R3 = Pullup-Resistor for Q1, R4 = Pulldown-Resistor for Q2

Are my suggestions right? Thank you for your answers!

Greetings, Christopher

[image: Safe Input for 74HCT165]

Comment: A couple serious issues- nothing limits base current to Q1 so it will die, there is no input current so the LED won't turn on.

Comment: Also, the inputs of the 74HCT165 (including D7) won't sink enough current to light up an LED.

Comment: Add a collector resistor to Q2 to limit Q1 base current, connect the cathode of LED1 to ground, and connect D7 to the collector of Q1. That should do what you want. I would also make R4 smaller (1k) so that the input is less sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with getting your circuit to function, then go on to make some suggested changes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq7Jp3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Part numbers refer to my schematic.

I've increased R5 to 10K from 1K because that much base current is not required. Your 1K would work (it's not wrong), and might be desirable for switch reliability in some cases.

I've decreased R6 from 100K to 10K because with 10K there is still plenty of base current and 60uA will better deal with pickup than 6uA. If R5 was 1K, I might go to 4.7K for R6 or even 1K. A diode (see below schematic) across R6 would also be good in either case, but I didn't want to change your schematic too much.

R4 is necessary to limit the base current of Q2. I've picked it roughly to ensure enough base current that Q2 saturates with about 20mA for the LED and a bit more for R3. R1 just deals with leakage of Q1, especially at high temperatures. It's typically not needed at room temperature, but you should put it in there anyway. Less than 1uA through Q1 is enough to create the wrong logic level at the output.

R2 determines LED current, and I've left it as is.

R3 is necessary because the LED does not conduct much current at low voltages and we want the input to be pulled down to ground when Q2 is off, not to float around at a volt or two.

The below circuit would work and would be simpler, though it does not have exactly the same function- the logic is reversed, which could easily be inverted in your firmware. Note I've added D2 to prevent reverse breakdown of Q1's base in case a large negative transient voltage appears on the long wire.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flEb3S.png)</sup>

Finally, and especially if the wire goes outdoors, you should consider using a completely separate 12V supply (grounds not even connected together) and optoisolators rather than transistors. That's outside the scope of your question, so I won't go into too many details, but it's almost as simple as replacing Q1 in your original circuit with the optoisolator.

Comment: Why would there appear negative voltages on the long wire? Because of the switching and the inductance of the wire?

Comment: @Golaž A lighting strike a few miles away would do it, as could your suggestion of wire inductance.